# How feasible is a 200km long tube with no curvature?

Tags: civil-engineering, construction-management

By no curvature I mean not following the earth's curvature. Would it be easier to tunnel the middle through the earth or raise the ends out of the earth? Is there anywhere that this kind of construction has been made and if so how much did it cost?

Comment: How deep have we drilled - and the diameter? How high would the ends be if the middle was on or just in the surface? Check out the longest tunnels and think about the length.

Comment: So, if the ends where on the surface, then by some rough calcs the depth would be 79km and we have managed to get down to 12 km...

Comment: Why would anyone want anything like this? (answering your final question)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  Maybe someone is making a really big laser interferometer?

Comment: @EricShain I see someone's got a Monday Sense of Humor :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  Actually the LIGO experiment which measured gravity waves works like this although their interferometer is only 4km long: https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/ligo-gw-interferometer.

Comment: @EricShain sure,  but heck, there are far longer tunnels in use for both traffic and for water.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_longest_tunnels  On the serious side, it's one thing to have a long open space with a laser at one end and a mirror at the other (roughly speaking); it's quite another to have that tunnel be perfectly straight (to a wavelength of offset) along the entire length .

Comment: Some issues: it would be extremely expensive - just being 200 km long would make it very expensive, making it dead horizontal for that length even more so. What tolerances would you allow to the tunnel being horizontal? What diameter, or height & width of tunnel? What construction method would be used: tunnel boring machine or drill & blast? Do you want the tunnel to be lined with concrete, thus having smooth walls, or just rough cut into the rock?

Comment: And how would you deal with the temperature if it was drilled / made ?

Comment: Was this an interview question for Elon Musk's Hyperloop project? ;)

Comment: @SolarMike how did you do the calculations for the depth it would need to be?

Comment: @alephzero I wish

Comment: @SRawes Apply this : http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.11/h/tim2.html , used distance to centre of 6371 km from https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/154357-earths-core-is-much-hotter-than-previously-thought-hotter-than-the-surface-of-the-sun

Comment: We should enshrine this question as a perfect example of a "[Naive design question](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/1832)". Just about every single comment is a question, showing how a simple ten-word question actually hides a multitude of design questions.

Comment: 360º/40000km*200km ~=1.8º -> 6300km * (1-COS 0.9) ~= 777m

Having that over the ground seem unpractical, while we already have tunnels close to that length and depth. Not cheap however.

Comment: I concur the estimate in the first comment is off by two decimal places. `0.79` km seems do-able.

Comment: @AdrianMaire which tunnels are already like that? What are they used for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_longest_tunnels